# Javascript - conditional formatting breaks after element reload using ".load"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reload

I'm very new to JavaScript / JQuery and having some issues with what should be a simple conditional formatting function.  The conditional formatting function itself works fine, on initial page load; however, after performing an element reload set to run every 60 seconds, it breaks the conditional formatting again.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ticker-item:contains("-")').css('color', 'red');
    $('.ticker-item:contains("+")').css('color', '#2FA702');
    $('.carousel-item h3:contains("Closed")').css('color', 'red');
    $('.carousel-item h3:contains("Open")').css('color', '#2FA702');
    });

var refreshTickers = setInterval(function () {
    $("#top-bar").load(location.href+" #top-bar>*","");
}, 60000);
```

It's probably worth mentioning that it's only the `ticker-item` formatting that's going wrong after the element reload.  The `carousel-item` formatting works fine.  The `ticker-item`s are inside the `#top-bar` element, whereas the `carousel-item`s are not, so to me it's clear that the issue is within the `#top-bar` element as a result of the reload.

I've also tried the below code, to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ticker-item:contains("-")').css('color', 'red');
    $('.ticker-item:contains("+")').css('color', '#2FA702');    
    $('.carousel-item h3:contains("Closed")').css('color', 'red');
    $('.carousel-item h3:contains("Open")').css('color', '#2FA702');
    });

var refreshTickers = setInterval(function () {
    $("#top-bar").load(location.href+" #top-bar>*","");
    $('.ticker-item:contains("-")').css('color', 'red');
    $('.ticker-item:contains("+")').css('color', '#2FA702');
}, 60000);
```

What's more strange is that with this code, if I change the interval for the reload to 10 seconds, it seems to break the formatting for a few seconds but then fix it again, almost as though it is waiting for the rest of the function to execute before catching up with itself.

As I said, I'm new to JS and I've searched everywhere for a solution to this.  Am I doing something wrong?

If you need anything else (i.e. HTML), please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you replace the content, whatever was applied to it before hand will not be applied to it when you set it back into the page.

Comment: @epascarello - I thought that might be the case.  However, shouldn't the second version of the code work?  (With the formatting included in the 'refreshTickers' function?)  Thanks for your help

Comment: if any of the answers resolve your issue make sure to accept it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want it to be done again and again you should create a separate function to that.

And the load function will trigger a callback whenever it completes you can use that callback to reformat it again.

```js
function reFormat(){
    $('.ticker-item:contains("-")').css('color', 'red');
    $('.ticker-item:contains("+")').css('color', '#2FA702');
    $('.carousel-item h3:contains("Closed")').css('color', 'red');
    $('.carousel-item h3:contains("Open")').css('color', '#2FA702');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   reFormat();

    var refreshTickers = setInterval(function () {
        $("#top-bar").load(location.href+" #top-bar>*", function(){
            reFormat();
        });
    }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  However, I tried this code and unfortunately it didn't work.  The formatting didn't show on the initial page load, nor did it reload the `#top-bar` element.  I understand the theory behind it though.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: what's the output on console ?

Comment: I have fixed  a syntax error. it should resolve your issue now.

Comment: That's great.  Thanks so much, I've spent hours trying to do that!

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `.load()`, it takes some amount of time to go get the new data and insert elements into the DOM. However, the subsequent Javascript code there doesn't know that it's supposed to wait until `.load()` has finished and created the new elements.

**In timeline form, what's currently happening is:**

1. call `.load()`
2. find and style any `.ticker-item` elements that are present
3. data received back from `.load()`
4. create new `.ticker-item` DOM elements

**What you want to happen:**

1. call `.load()`
2. wait until data received back from `.load()`
3. create new `.ticker-item` DOM elements
4. find and style any `.ticker-item` elements that are present

**[Anees' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61548219/129086) is exactly what you want**: consolidate your formatting code into a single function, then call that as a callback function after `.load()` has finished.

As you progress in learning JavaScript, check out `Promises` and `async`/`await` as well.

---

**EDIT:**

There may still be a subtle delay between `.load()` finishing and those elements being present in the DOM.

One way to find out if that's the case would be to add a delay before calling `reFormat()` in the callback:

```js
var elementCreationDelay = 500; // experiment with this duration

var refreshTickers = setInterval(function () {
  $("#top-bar").load(location.href+" #top-bar>*", function(){
    setTimeout(reFormat, elementCreationDelay);
}, 60000);
```

Comment: Thanks for this response - very informative.  However, Anees' code unfortunately didn't work, though I understand the process behind it.  Thanks

Comment: I've added another suggestion in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you.  It turns out there was a syntax error in Anees' answer.  It's now been resolved.  Thanks for your help